# Adding new row to a column in pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have 2 pivot tables: dfp1 and dfp2.

My current code is:

```
if not dfp2.empty:
 for key in dfp1['col1'].keys():
  if key not in dfp2['col2'].keys():
   dfp2['col2'][key] = 0
```

The purpose is to check if a value exist in col1 of dfp1 exists in col2 of dfp2. If not, make it 0.

However this does not add the value to dfp2['col2']. How should I go to add this 0 value?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Some sample data:

dfp1['col1']

```
*Currency Code
CNH         0.00
INR         0.00
JPY   -985718.00
SGD       -70.69
USD      9103.94
```

dfp2['col2']

```
JPY    8030442.00
MYR     153050.00
SGD     636836.44
USD     553863.09
```

Expected output for dfp2['col2']:

```
JPY    8030442.00
MYR     153050.00
SGD     636836.44
USD     553863.09
CNH     0.00
INR     0.00
```

Comment: have you tried pd.merge() then use df.fillna(0)? It would be helpful if you show a sample of your data

Comment: Can you share sample data and expected output, to help you better.

Comment: I've added the sample data to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Solution with `Series.align`

We can `align` the two columns along the index axis

```
col2 = dfp2['col2'].align(dfp1['col1'], fill_value=0)[0]
```

##### Solution with `Series.reindex`

```
col2 = dfp2['col2'].reindex(dfp2.index.union(dfp1.index), fill_value=0)
```

---

```
print(col2)

CNH          0.00
INR          0.00
JPY    8030442.00
MYR     153050.00
SGD     636836.44
USD     553863.09
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```